# Comparing files, but ignoring specific differences, in a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a shell script that compares files of the same name across two directories and alerts me to differences.  Most of the time the files files in a new batch are unchanged but occasionally one changes and I need to take some action. I'm trying to update my script to ignore minor differences that I don't care about, specifically Expiration and Signature tags in Amazon S3 URL's.

My current script uses cmp to just compare the files exactly:

```
if ! cmp --silent ${i} ${COMPARE_DIR}/${i}; then
  echo "$i : TAKE ACTION"
fi
```

I worked out fairly quickly on the command line a way to regex out the offending pattern using sed:

```
cmp <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" file1.json) <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" ../other/file1.json)
```

For the life of me I can't figure out the syntax to make this work in my script. First it complained about the parentheses, and after escaping those I got an oh-so-helpful `No such file or directory` error. Nothing else I've tried improves things.

Any suggestions? Is there a better way to get at what I want?

Comment: `<( process substitution )` is a **bash/ksh/zsh** construct, so make sure your script does NOT use `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: I fail to see how the accepted answer actually answers your question and solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the line `cmp <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" file1.json) <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" ../other/file1.json)` works properly, you can check the result as follows:

```
cmp <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" file1.json) <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" ../other/file1.json)
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ] ; then
    echo "$i : TAKE ACTION"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

> First it complained about the parentheses, and after escaping those I got an oh-so-helpful No such file or directory error.

Most probably your script is running as Bash. Make sure the first line is `#!/bin/bash` (or wherever you have Bash in your system).
This is because the `<(...)` is Bash specific, and may not be supported in `/bin/sh` or whatever it's linked to.

For example, if the first line of your script is `#!/bin/sh`, then you will get an error like this:

> script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Then, as you say, you "escaped the parentheses", like `<\(sed -e ...\)`, the shell will interpret that as input redirection from a file, and since you don't have such file (a file named "(sed"), the `No such file or directory` error is exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If your action can be written as a single command or function call, you can use the `&&` and `||` operators to replace `if-then` and `else` for a really messy one-liner:

```
 cmp <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" file1.json) <(sed -e "s/Expires.*3D/Expires3D/" ../other/file1.json) && echo "$i : TAKE ACTION" || echo "$i: No Action"
```